# boost geometry + WGS84, does latitude and longitude, but not altitude?

Tags: c++, boost, gis, latitude-longitude, boost-geometry

I'm looking to do a couple of calculations over a WGS84 ellipsoid, including: point in polygon on the surface, distance calculations between points, and conversion to/from Cartesian coordinates. It looks like there is a GIS extension to boost geometry that basically does what I need - except that it doesn't appear to convert altitudes to/from Cartesian coordinates - only X/Y and Lat/Lon. Am I missing something? Is this possible? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the omission is because there are very few places in the world where the WGS84 ellipsoid [actually corresponds to sea level](http://www.gpspassion.com/forumsen/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10915).

But as for the mathematics itself, I can suggest [this article](https://geodesy.noaa.gov/TOOLS/XYZ/xyz.shtml), supplies conversions from lat-long-altitude (LLA) to Cartesian and back, and references the mathematics behind those conversions.